# Clicking divs in correct order

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I make it so that when you press the divs in the correct order something happends.

Here's my code so far.
Now something only happends if you click on all of the teal colored divs.

```js
var one = false;
var two = false;
var three = false;
var four = false;
function mm(x) {
  var y = x.id;
  switch (y) {
    case "one":
      one = true;
      break;
    case "two":
      two = true;
      break;
    case "three":
      three = true;
      break;
    case "four":
      four = true;
  }
  x.style.background = "aqua";
  if (one == true && two == true && three == true && four == true) {
    alert("WOW");
    one = false;
    two = false;
    three = false;
    four = false;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("dev");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      x[i].style.backgroundColor = "teal";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  background: #333;
}
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.dev {
  background-color: teal;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100vh;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.one {
  left: 1%;
}
.two {
  left: 27%;
}
.three {
  right: 27%;
}
.four {
  right: 1%;
}
```

```html
<div onclick="mm(this);" id="one" class="dev one"></div>
<div onclick="mm(this);" id="two" class="dev two"></div>
<div onclick="mm(this);" id="three" class="dev three"></div>
<div onclick="mm(this);" id="four" class="dev four"></div>
```

If there is an easier way of doing it than making lots of variables and ifs and switches, it would be nice.

No jQuery please. 
**Thank you.**

Comment: can you please clarify the term "correct order"?

Comment: Like, if I first press the second one then the third, fourt and first div somethings happends

Comment: still, I cannot figure out "order"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing to come to my mind is keep the order in an array and match it against a data attribute on the divs. The end case will be if the next index is the same as the arrays length.

Here's an example:

```js
let divs = document.querySelectorAll("div");
for (let i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
  divs[i].addEventListener("click", checkOrder);
}

// the contents match the data-index for the divs
// this means the div with the data-index 2 will be the first in
// the correct order
let orderArray = [2, 3, 0, 1];
let nextIndex = 0;

function checkOrder() {
  divIndex = parseInt(this.dataset.index);
  
  // if the user did not choose the correct next item then restart
  if (divIndex !== orderArray[nextIndex]) {
    console.log("Incorrect- restarting");
    resetDivs();
    nextIndex = 0;
    return;
  }

  // user got the right next div. Color the selected div
  this.style.backgroundColor = "aqua";
  
  // check end case
  if(nextIndex === divs.length - 1){
    console.log("congratulations you won, you guessed the order " + orderArray);
  }
  
  // Set the next index in the order the user needs to match
  nextIndex++;
}

function resetDivs() {
  for (let i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    divs[i].style.backgroundColor = "teal";
  }
}
```

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  background: #333;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.dev {
  background-color: teal;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100vh;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.one {
  left: 1%;
}

.two {
  left: 27%;
}

.three {
  right: 27%;
}

.four {
  right: 1%;
}
```

```html
<div data-index="0" class="dev one"></div>
<div data-index="1" class="dev two"></div>
<div data-index="2" class="dev three"></div>
<div data-index="3" class="dev four"></div>
```

Comment: It seems like this defeats the purpose of guessing a sequential order if you automatically restart them on the first incorrect selection, no? It should allow them to guess the entire sequence and then pass/fail and reset.

Comment: sure, whatever the OP wants to do I'm sure he can do it from this example (which is all it is)

Answer (score 1):

Every time you need so many variables, ex. `var one, two, three, four;`, consider other data type for example an array. I present you a solution below, which stores correct order in `correctOrder` array, and actual order in `order` array. Every time a block is clicked, first item in `order` array is deleted with `Array.prototype.shift` and new one is added with `Array.prototype.push`. This way you always have last 4 clicked blocks' names in `order` array, so you can compare it to your `correctOrder`:

```
order.join("") === correctOrder.join("")
```

Note that straight array comparison wouldn't work here.

It's just a hint in the right direction; code still needs improvement but notice how you can avoid a lot of unnecessary code.

```js
var correctOrder = ["two", "three", "one", "four"];
var order = ["", "", "", ""];
var blocks = document.querySelectorAll(".dev");
blocks.forEach(block => block.addEventListener("click", mm));
function mm() {
  order.shift();
  order.push(this.id);
  this.style.background = "aqua";
  if (order.join("") === correctOrder.join("")) {
    alert("WOW");
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("dev");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      x[i].style.backgroundColor = "teal";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  background: #333;
}
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.dev {
  background-color: teal;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100vh;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.one {
  left: 1%;
}
.two {
  left: 27%;
}
.three {
  right: 27%;
}
.four {
  right: 1%;
}
```

```html
<div id="one" class="dev one"></div>
<div id="two" class="dev two"></div>
<div id="three" class="dev three"></div>
<div id="four" class="dev four"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
  var columns = document.querySelectorAll('.dev'),
      sequence = '1234',
      order = [],
      reset = function(){
        order = [];
        columns.forEach(function(column){
          column.style.backgroundColor = 'teal';
        });
      };

  columns.forEach(function(column){
    column.addEventListener('click', function(){
      var data = this.dataset,
          index = order.indexOf(data.index),
          bgColor = index > -1 ? 'teal' : 'aqua';

      if(index > -1){
        order.splice(index, 1);
      }else{
        order.push(data.index);
      }

      this.style.backgroundColor = bgColor;

      if(order.length === sequence.length){          
        if(order.join('') === sequence){
          alert('You guessed the correct order!');
        }else{
          alert('Please try again!')
        }

        reset();
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  background: #333;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.dev {
  background-color: teal;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 100vh;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 20%;
}

.one {
  left: 1%;
}

.two {
  left: 27%;
}

.three {
  right: 27%;
}

.four {
  right: 1%;
}
```

```html
<div class="dev one" data-index="1"></div>
<div class="dev two" data-index="2"></div>
<div class="dev three" data-index="3"></div>
<div class="dev four" data-index="4"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
var sequence = [], //to store the current pressed sequence
    code = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']; //the expected sequence for something to happen

//function that given a step, will return true or false if the sequence is correct
function checkStep (item, sequence, code) {
    sequence.push(item);
    if (sequence.length > code.length) {
        sequence.shift();
    }

    return sequence.join() === code.join();
}
```

That piece of code alone is to check the sequence alone, an example using the code above: (the expected sequence is `['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']`)

```
checkStep('three'); //false, current sequence is ['three']
checkStep('one'); //false, current sequence is ['three', 'one']
checkStep('two'); //false, current sequence is ['three', 'one', 'two']
checkStep('three'); //false, current sequence is ['three', 'one', 'two', 'three']
checkStep('four'); //true, current sequence is ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']
```

Your js could look like this:

```js
var sequence = [], //to store the current pressed sequence
    code = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']; //the expected sequence for something to happen

//function that given a step, will return true or false if the sequence is correct
function checkStep (item, sequence, code) {
    sequence.push(item);
    if (sequence.length > code.length) {
        sequence.shift();
    }

    return sequence.join() === code.join();
}

function mm(x) {
    var y = x.id;

    x.style.background = "aqua";
    if (checkStep(y, sequence, code)) {
        alert("WOW");
        sequence = []; //reset the current sequence
        var x = document.getElementsByClassName("dev");
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            x[i].style.backgroundColor = "teal";
        }
    }
}
```

```css
body,
html {
    height: 100%;
    background: #333;
}

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.dev {
    background-color: teal;
    width: 20%;
    height: 100vh;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.one {
    left: 1%;
}

.two {
    left: 27%;
}

.three {
    right: 27%;
}

.four {
    right: 1%;
}
```

```html
<div onclick="mm(this);" id="one" class="dev one"></div>
<div onclick="mm(this);" id="two" class="dev two"></div>
<div onclick="mm(this);" id="three" class="dev three"></div>
<div onclick="mm(this);" id="four" class="dev four"></div>
```

Comment: Should the HTML be the same. Because in that case this doesnt work.